Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: The specified module could not be found
I want to learn how to use hardhat. When use "npx hardhat node", it always report error.I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
npx hardhat node
Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\D:\hardhat\node_modules\@nomicfoundation\edr-win32-x64-msvc\edr.win32-x64-msvc.node

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH604 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces

I've tried switching node versions，but it didn't work。
